# How to set fontSize for Text (Jetpack Compose) from res xml?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I have my `dimen.xml` with all demintions that I use over the app. Now with jetpack compose I would like to use these demintions also here

There is a text:

```
...
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.brandname),
        fontSize = 12.sp
    )
...
```

I can get text from the resources, however, I can't get `12.sp` value from `dimen.xml`, I am trying to do it like this

```
...
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = R.string.brandname),
        fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.brandname_size)
    )
...
```

I got an error in the `fontSize` line - type mismatch, required `TextUnit`, found `Dp`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should just be `fontSize = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.brandname_size).value.sp`